# mathematical model

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question: $g$ varies directly with $f$ and inversely with $c$ and the square of $d$. So we have to setup the equation given that information. Looking at my notes a bit it seems like it might be  $g = \frac{kf}{cd}$ but it just seems a bit odd as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I think there's a better answer here:

"$g$ varies directly with $f$..."
$$g=k\cdot f$$

"...and inversely with $c$..."

$$g=k\cdot \frac{f}{c}$$

"...and with the square of $d$."

$$g=k\cdot \frac{f}{cd^2}$$

Comment: Thank you didnt realize I forgot the square on the d